# Synchronize multiple weblogic database access

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

We have multiple instances of weblogic running on a server.
All these instances access only a single database.

One of the table stores the requests that we need to process.
Issue is more than one weblogic can access the database at a given time and can pick the request and process it.
Due to this one request gets processed multiple times & creates issues.

These is no use of creating an extra attribute in the DB which stores the flag whether that record is processed or not as 2 weblogic can access that record in the very same time.

The code that access the database is Java, but no use of making that part synchronized as, each weblogic has there separate copy of code.

Please suggest how can we make sure that one record gets processed only one time by multiple running weblogics.

Comment: Look at Oracle Advanced Queues.  You can publish table records to a queue and have multiple consumers.  See whitepaper - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/data-integration/oracle-aq-tech-wp11-2-191324.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer depends upon, how you are accessing DB, using API like hibernate or simple JDBC. One thing you can do is, you can manage this thru session. Once the record is accessed, it becomes `DIRTY` and hence will not be accessed next time. You surely need to add some mechanism how ever which can let your application know that, "Which requests are processed and which are not".

> 2 weblogic can access that record in the very same time.

This seems horrible to me, so that, you need to ensure atomicity for sure. I guess, (not sure) when one web logic accesses it, it occupy lock on transaction. Another web logic should have another fresh copy of the same record, indeed after releasing the lock).

Hope this helps.